# System of distinct representatives for sets graph theory

Tags: graph-theory

Working through some questions to do with  graph theory but am stuck on the following questiond.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kvjvl.jpg)

Now I know that if I can show that if every possible union of the sets A1,...,An have atleast n elements in them, then this collection has a system of distinct representatives but unsure how to get here.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Define a bipartite graph whose vertices on one side represent the sets $A_i$, and whose vertices on the other are the elements of the set. Draw an edge from $A_i$ to $x$ if $x\in A_i$.

Observe that the condition in the question is now exactly Hall’s condition, and so there is a matching from the sets to their elements. This matching gives a distinct representative for each $A_i$